# I get some errors trying to install cpXstack. It fails at the end

Tags: nginx, cpanel, php, whm

I'm trying to install cpXstack on my site http://tequierocali.org, But it fails every time I try to get it done.

I get the following errors, I wonder if anybody has figured this out:

```
Complete!
sed: can't read /var/spool/incron/root: No such file or directory
PID unreadable in: /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/data/master-qrunner.pid
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/data/master-qrunner.pid'
Is qrunner even running?
/etc/exim.pl.local.build syntax OK
PID unreadable in: /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/data/master-qrunner.pid
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/data/master-qrunner.pid'
Is qrunner even running?
/etc/exim.pl.local.build syntax OK
info [rebuildhttpdconf] 'local' datastore in use (/var/cpanel/conf/apache/local)
Built /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf OK
Waiting for httpd to restart................finished.

httpd (/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL) running as root with PID 10333 (pidfile check method)

Apache successfully restarted.
[10366] [2013-02-07 06:36:31 +0200] [main] Current process '20664' stopped
[Thu Feb  7 06:36:32 2013] Starting /usr/local/cpanel/libexec/tailwatch/tailwatchd daemon
Log is at /usr/local/cpanel/logs/tailwatchd_log
cat: /opt/pifpm/pifpm.config: No such file or directory
./cpxstack.sh: line 39: /etc/init.d/php-fpm-5.3.21: No such file or directory
error reading information on service php-fpm-5.3.21: No such file or directory
./cpxstack.sh: line 39: /etc/init.d/php-fpm-5.4.11: No such file or directory
error reading information on service php-fpm-5.4.11: No such file or directory
Installation failed: contact cpxstack@sysally.net
```

Thanks,

Caro

Comment: No need to include names as signature in your posts, its already there below your posts!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the initial stages of the error to understand what is really happening .

I am one of the programmers of this plugin ;I can assist you better if you provide the exact reason why the install failed .